# Associations with Rails Admin & Visible Fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I currently have three models, each with associations set up between them that I'm looking to manage using Rails_Admin but there seem to be issues when it comes to displaying those associations in the front-end forms.

The models & associations look like the following (syntax notwithstanding):

```
    Customer - has_many :orders
    Seller - has_many :orders
    Order - has_one :customer, has_one :seller
```

When I open up Rails_Admin, I get a blank space next to the label "Customer" and "Seller" I then performed add_reference on the models so that Customers and Sellers contain `order_id` and Orders contains `customer_id` and `seller_id`

When I did that, four new fields appeared in the view for Order:

```
    Customer - integer field
    Seller - integer field
    Customer - searchable dropdown field
    Seller - searchable dropdown field
```

I only want the searchable dropdowns but the integer fields appear (presumably since `add_references` adds an integer field to the table) and I can't get rid of the integer fields. Why are they appearing if Rails_Admin is already detecting the association?

Also, when editing an `Order` with an existing `Customer` or `Seller`, the searchable dropdown field appears empty as if I'm inputting a new value rather than pre-loading it with the saved value.

Suggestions on how to remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.

I changed the association for `Order` to `belongs_to :customer` and `belongs_to :seller` and manually added the following columns to `Order`:

```
    customer_id:integer
    seller_id:integer
```